# Intranet site asking for credentials when using anonymous access

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an intranet site hosting RESTful services via ASP.NET WebAPI.

I am having an issue where all browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE) are displaying a login prompt requesting credentials.  I am hosting the site in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Home Premium with Anonymous Access enabled.

The root URL `http://localhost/RootAPI/` should be viewable to anonymous users, but the private routes, e.g. `http://localhost/RootAPI/Invoice` and `http://localhost/RootAPI/Order` should be accessed only to authenticated users via the `[Authorize]` attribute.  I am intending to control the authentication process using WebAPI calls via AngularJS once I have fixed this issue.

My website uses the ASP.NET v4.0 app pool identity and I have assigned read permissions to the application's folder for this user.

I have also added `http://localhost` to the list of trusted sites in IE as well as checking the 'Allow Integrated Windows Authentication' in the Advanced options in IE.  Furthermore, the 'Automatic login with current user name and password' is checked in the custom level for the Intranet sites and the issue still persists.

I have got this in my web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

When viewing the log files under `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1` it does not display the user name (I was expecting to see the anonymous user name) and shows HTTP status 401.

I've spend two days on this frustrating issue and I cannot stop the logon prompt from appearing.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after discovering the custom authorization filter was being executed and was checking to see if the controller was decorated with `[AllowAnonymousAttribute()]` and it wasn't.

After adding this attribute to the root controller I no longer received login prompts.

This is what the root controller looks like after adding the attribute filter:

```
[AllowAnonymousAttribute()]
public class RootController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

The root page now displays as expected.